# Why is SQLite compiled with the OMIT_LOOKASIDE option in Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: 18.04, source-code, sqlite

I am working on a project using SQLite and I need an option enabled that is not enabled in the version installed on my Ubuntu 18.04.1 box.  No big deal - I can easily grab the source and build my own version.  In looking at the compile options of the installed version, I noticed that SQLite is built with the [OMIT_LOOKASIDE](https://www.sqlite.org/compile.html#_options_to_omit_features) option which changes how [SQLite manages memory](https://www.sqlite.org/malloc.html#lookaside).

Why was this compilation option chosen?

Edited to add:

Installed version of SQLite is 3.22.0.

Comment: You have SQLite 2 or 3 ?

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy Thanks - forgot to add the version of SQLite - it's 3.22.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The lookaside option apparently is disabled in upstream debian package because it [lead to crashes in libsqlite-3 as per bug #615061](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=615061). The referenced bug report is also mentioned in the changelog of the 3.22.0-1 package version (sorry for the image of text, currently working in VM without clipboard supoprt):

[image]

Comment: Thanks!  Was this issue ever reported back to the SQLite developers?  I couldn't find it in their tracking system, but I could have missed it.

Comment: @user2676699 I am not aware of any such reports, but it may be worthwhile to send an email to their mailing list. I can do that, or if you want - feel free to do so. I wouldn't submit an actual bug report yet in case it already exists, though.